# Screen recorder crashes when I move the form window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have followed a bunch of tutorials and made a screen recorder. It works by taking a screenshot and then using the `AForge.video` addon to convert this to avi format. The programme worked fine, but it ran out of memory after about 20 seconds. This would either crash the program or clear itself with a huge lag spike. To stop this I added a disposal method at the end of every screenshot to clear the memory. This kept the memory usage down however it makes the application hugely unstable. When I move the main window or wait for about 3 minutes on recording, the programme crashes and shows this:
[A screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52pQM.png)

Every time I remove the dispose methods, the programme moves fine but runs out of memory quickly. Maybe I'm just using the dispose method wrong.

Here's the code that crashes the programme. There is way to much code to include it all.

```
 counter = 0;
 imagelist = new Bitmap[100000];
 Globals.imgcount = 0;
 Graphics g;

 basePath = sel.ToString();
 basePath = @"C:\Users\sim\Videos\Captures";
 using (var videowriter = new VideoFileWriter())
 {
     videowriter.Open(basePath + "timelapse.avi", Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, 9, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1200000);

     while (Globals.recording == true) 
     {
         try
         {                       
             try
             {                      
                 //takes the screenshot                            
                 bm = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                 //turns it into graphics
                 g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
                 g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size);

                 counter++;                                    

                 videowriter.WriteVideoFrame(bm);

                 //display image
                 Bitmap original = bm;
                 Bitmap resized2 = new Bitmap(original, new Size(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height));
                 bm = resized2;

                 pictureBox1.Image = bm;                                                       

                 Thread.Sleep(10);

                 if (/*counter % 18 == 0*/ true) 
                 {
                    try
                    {
                        g.Dispose();
                        bm.Dispose();

                        original.Dispose();
                        resized2.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Disposal error");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        catch { }
    }                
    videowriter.Close();
}
```

I hope that this is enough information to figure something out.
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Where are you running this code from?

Comment: I'm running this code in a : private void capture ()  {  }. this code is called from a button press

Comment: Before you call `bm.Dispose` set `pictureBox1.Image` to null.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. it worked clearing the picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing many things unnecessary eg creating 3 bitmaps instead of one, setting the image *bm* to picbox and of cource running the code to main UI. Of cource it will freeze. For an easy and quick fix create a timer. Set the interval to 10. Create a `button` that will stop the timer and one that will start it and record. In timer instead of calling
repeatedly

```
pictureBox1.Image = bm;
```

use

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```

Code:

```
//not good names. change it to something meaningfull
private Bitmap bm;
private Graphics g;
VideoFileWriter videowriter;

private void timer1_Tick( object sender, EventArgs e ) {;
    //takes the screenshot                            
    g.CopyFromScreen( 0, 0, 0, 0, bm.Size );

    videowriter.WriteVideoFrame(bm);

    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

The button that starts the recording:

```
private void Start_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    //create both bitmap and graphics once!
    bm = new Bitmap( Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height );
    g = Graphics.FromImage( bm );

    pictureBox1.Image = bm; //Just once!

    basePath = sel.ToString();
    basePath = @"C:\Users\sim\Videos\Captures";
    videowriter = new VideoFileWriter();
    videowriter.Open(basePath + "timelapse.avi", Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, 9, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1200000);

    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Button to stop recording:

```
private void Stop_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    timer1.Enabled = false;

    pictureBox1.Image = null;
    bm.Dispose();
    bm = null;
    g.Dispose();
    g = null;
    videowriter.Close();
    //I don't know if videowriter can be disposed if so dispose it too and set it to null
}
```

Also set `picturebox` *SizeMode* to *StreachImage*

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking this script works amazingly, thank you so much for the detailed help.